# Average integral increasing

Tags: real-analysis

I have a simple question but I have been struggling to prove it. Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Then 
$F(x)= {1 \over x} \int_0^x f(t)dt$ is non-decreasing.

I tried to proceed as follows: take $x\geq y$, then $F(x)={1 \over x}\int_0^y f(t)dt+{1 \over x}\int_y^x f(t)dt\geq {y \over x}f(0)+{(x-y) \over x}f(y)$ but it does not get me anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: First step:  Find $F(y)-F(x)$. Then, assume $y>x$ and see what conclusions  you can draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ 0<x<y\leq1$

with the change $u=\frac{t}{x}$,

$F(x)$ becomes

$$F(x)=\int_0^1f(xu)du$$

then

$$F(x)-F(y)=\int_0^1 (f(xu)-f(yu))du\leq 0$$

since

$$\forall u\in[0,1]\;\; xu\leq yu$$

and $f$ increasing.

Answer (score 2):

We have for $y \le x$
\begin{align*}
  F(x) &= \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t)\, dt\\
       &= \frac 1x \int_0^y f\left(\frac xy s\right)\, \frac xy\, ds\\
       &= \frac 1y \int_0^y f\left(\frac xy s\right)\, ds\\
       &\ge \frac 1y \int_0^y f(s)\, ds\\
       &= F(y).
\end{align*}